# How to reduce body fat?

Tags: running, exercise, gym, upper-body-workout

I've decided to reduce fat, I want to increase my stamina as I feel tiered after walking a half mile and my final target is to get 6-pack abs and good biceps , triceps and chest.

**Introduction:**

I'm 23 years old boy , 171 cm long and 70-75 kg weighted

**Background:**

For last 2 years , I've been sitting in the chair for 8-8 hours in a row to work/study . But now I understand health is the most important thing .

I've not done any kind of exercise before but now I'm very serious.

**Want to know:**

Please tell me what I should do. I want to reduce my side ,belly , face fat and man boobs too.

I am ready to anything ( GYM , yoga, running etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: While not specific to your question this answer will help you get started until you get some specific answers: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12860/beginner-in-physical-fitness-need-tips-and-advices/12864#12864  Basically, you need to get your food intake in line and work out an exercise and activity program that becomes part of your life.  Good luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You reduce body fat by being in a caloric deficit (burning more calories than you eat/drink). You build muscle by having a positive nitrogen balance (usually by having enough protein in your system). Balancing those two things can be tricky at times, but is definitely possible, especially for those new to muscle building. And yes, you’ll want to focus on building muscle if you want to get the most out of fat loss.

So what does that look like in practice? Well, you’ll probably want to have a protein shake shortly after you work out to maximize protein absorption, and you’ll want to make sure you get some protein from other sources throughout the day. Plan out your meals in advance and monitor your weight. The range of weight loss that you’re looking for is neutral (zero) - 1 lb (0.45kg) per week.

What about the workouts themselves? You’ll want something with cardio of course, but you’ll also want something that focuses on muscle building. More than anything, you’ll want to cough up some cash and save yourself A LOT of time and misery by following a competent program. My suggestion? Search Google or YouTube for “ATHLEAN-X”. I’m about halfway through their AX-1 program (the one for beginners) and I’m starting to see some good results. But if you choose not to go with that program, just find another one that seems reputable.

Comment: this is actually what I'm looking for , thanks!

Comment: Is it really possible to build muscles if you are being in a caloric deficit (with or without positive nitrogen balance)  (indeed I don't agree with you) ? (1) By the way, are short reps recommended to avoid from loosing muscle, if you want to reduce body fat (i.e. : according to me, being in a caloric deficit AND by having a positive nitrogen balance) (2) ?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler If you are new to lifting, then it is definitely possible. Without a positive nitrogen balance it probably won’t happen, but getting enough protein isn’t too hard with a protein shake and planning out your food ahead of time. You want to get 1.5-2.0 times your kg bodyweight in grams of protein. New lifters are able to do this because they have plenty of room for muscle growth. If you look like a muscular fitness model though, you won’t be able to do this, and if you go into a deficit that is too big, you’ll won’t get the results that you’re looking for either.

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler as for rep count, 12 is considered the standard. As long as you work your muscles to failure or close to it, you’ll be on the path to building muscle. The specific number isn’t too important really, as long as you’re challenging yourself appropriately.